# Selenium does not get table's body

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a table usign selenium but I'm running into the following problem. When I run:

```
stats_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='mcStatsTab statsSection season-so-far wrapper col-12 active']//table")
stats_html = stats_box.get_attribute('outerHTML')
print(stats_html)
```

All I get is this:

```
<table>
<thead>
"FULL HEAD IS HERE"
</thead>
<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"></tbody>
</table>
```

As you can see, I get the head, but the body, which is the part I need, is empty. The full HTML is in the image below. I'm sorry to post an Image but I was not able to post the HTML in a readable way.

[HTML here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnIhx.jpg)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: @chitown88 https://www.premierleague.com/match/46608

Comment: Got the same error. Do not know whats going on, but I've got it already. THanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am only assuming this is what you are after. Does this look right?

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.premierleague.com/match/46608')

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mainContent"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]')))
elem.click()

time.sleep(5)

dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)

for df in dfs:
    if len(df) > 10:
        print (df)
driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
    Crystal Palace       Unnamed: 1  Everton
0             35.4     Possession %     64.6
1              2.0  Shots on target      3.0
2              6.0            Shots     10.0
3            467.0          Touches    722.0
4            268.0           Passes    500.0
5             21.0          Tackles     14.0
6             21.0       Clearances     18.0
7              6.0          Corners      2.0
8              4.0         Offsides      0.0
9              2.0     Yellow cards      1.0
10             0.0        Red cards      1.0
11            16.0   Fouls conceded     14.0
```

Explaining the `.page_source` and `dfs` parts:

So with Selenium, you absolutely can parse the page and pull out the data you want using selenium exclusively. I personally am more familiar with BeautifulSoup. What `driver.page_source` does is just pulls the html source from the page thats open on your Selenium browser. and what you could do is feed that into beausitfulsoup with `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')`

However, if I'm after `<table>` tags, I don't bother with BeautifulSoup (although nothing wrong with using it to parse tables). But `Pandas` has a `.read_html()` function (that actually uses BeautifulSoup under the hood) to parse `<table>` tags. So rather than feed the html in bs4, I fed it into pandas with `dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)`

this will return a list of dataframes/table for each `<table>` tag it parses in the html. So after you use `.read_html()`, it's just a matter of pulling out the correct table in that list of tables it returned.

Then from there you can manipulate the dataframe as needed.

Comment: WOW that's exactly what I'm looking for. I had it figured out until de `.click()` but then I could not finish the job. Did not quite understand the `.page_source`  method tough and how it returns DFs, but that's ok. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm headed to bed now, but I'll add an explanation to that in the solution tomorrow.

Comment: I will really appreciate that. Thanks!